# setting a parameter in a proc

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am working or a report that you can enter a client number to view all the detail. I have been asked to to make a change where their can enter the client code or 0600 for all clients with the start name 'Jim Bob' or 0400 for clients name that start with 'Joe Bob' I had come up the the statement below but it does not work, can someone help me out. I am using sql 2008

```
where case when (@ClientCode = 0600 then c.sClientName Like 'Jim Bob%')   else
when (@ClientCode = 0400 then c.sClientName like 'Joe Bob%') else 
c.sClientCode = @ClientCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `CASE` in your scenario, it is enough to use correct combination of `AND` and `OR` statements:

```
where 
    -- Next line is used only when client code is 0600
    @ClientCode = 0600 and c.sClientName Like 'Jim Bob%' OR
   -- Next line is used only when client code is 0400
    @ClientCode = 0400 and c.sClientName like 'Joe Bob%' OR 
    -- Next line is used only when client code is not 0400 or 0600
    @ClientCode NOT IN (0400, 0600) AND c.sClientCode = @ClientCode
```

By the way, if your client type is text type (e.g. `varchar`, `nvarchar` or similar) you need to use quotes, like `'0600'` instead of `0600`. If this is numeric type then you don't need 0 at the start and you can use `600` instead of `0600`